# What is the wattage of my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, power, charger

I am trying to make a transportable charger for iPhones, but before I can start this I need to know how much power my iPhone uses when I make an emergency call.

If nobody knows this, I will be glad to have any information related to this.

Answer (score 2):

[Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4971/apple-iphone-4s-review-att-verizon/15) has some nice charts detailing the wattage of the iPhone 4S running various apps, which could be a good starting point for you.

You may also want to check out existing kits/projects, such as [MintyBoost](http://www.ladyada.net/make/mintyboost/) - they seem to work reasonably well with iPhones. There's a specific MintyBoost [page](http://www.ladyada.net/make/mintyboost/icharge.html) detailing Apple device charging that may also yield some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

The power use is going to vary somewhat depending on external factors on the RF side. Network mode in use (GSM/3G) and the power required to establish a stable connection to the cell site in use together with any other usage on the device (speaker/bluetooth/GPS)

Best guess is that your baseline should be the specified 1A required to charge the device and work up/down from there with a meter connected